# Git: Strategy for Dealing with Merge Conflicts?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge, git-pull

I use a private repository on Bitbucket as a convenient way of syncing a project (C source code) across several machines I work on; I am the only developer working on the project.

When working on a remote machine (I ssh to it) and trying to `git pull` I get the following error message:

"You are in the middle of a conflicted merge."

It exits without doing the fast forward merge.

How do I go about resolving this? How do I force a merge on this machine?

I am not averse to trying to reset to an earlier state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are in the middle of a prior merge attempt that had some conflicts.  Your first step would be to understand what happened and where you are.  Do

```
git status
```

This will show you what files are conflicted.  Once you understand what happened you can decide to resolve the conflicts (see the link provided by @rcdmk).  If, instead, you decide you just want to blow away the prior merge, then you can do:

```
git merge --abort
```

But you'll want to be very careful with this as stuff will disappear.  You will be okay if the remote has everything you want; so follow up with:

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 1):

When you face merge conflicts, there's a lot of options to follow, but you can consult the Git manual on this topic for a help. Also, a similar question has been asked here:
[How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)